# Arduino Multi-tasking

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to see if I can combine tasks that are currently being handled by two separate Arduino Unos onto a single Uno. I was shown the Adafruit guide to "multi-tasking" on the Arduino ([Link)](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1.pdf) and thought I would give it a try.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but my code is just not working...

I'm controlling a series of solenoids. They need to each act based on individual timing. I created a Solenoid class that handles telling the solenoid when to start and then monitor when to close it. For the life of me I can't see where my error is, but I never wind up satisfying my end condition.

```
class Solenoid {
  //Class Variables
  int solenoidPin;
  long chargeTime;
  long ventTime;
  bool started = false;
  unsigned long startMillis;
  unsigned long endMillis;
  unsigned long previousMillis;
  int solenoidState;

  //Constructor
public:
  Solenoid(int pin, long charge, long vent) {
    solenoidPin = pin;
    pinMode(solenoidPin, OUTPUT);
    chargeTime = charge;
    ventTime = vent;
    solenoidState = LOW;
    previousMillis = 0;
}
  void Start() {
    Serial.println("Start called");
    started = true;
  }

  void Update() {
    //Check to see if it is time to change the state of the solenoid
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    Serial.println("Update");
    if((started == true) && (currentMillis-previousMillis <= chargeTime)) {
      //Run
      Serial.print("Run: Charge Time=");
      Serial.print(chargeTime);
      Serial.print("  current-previous=");
      Serial.println(currentMillis-previousMillis);
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    } else if ((started == true) && (currentMillis-previousMillis >= chargeTime)){
      //Stop
      Serial.println("Stop");
    }
  }
};

//Setup the solenoids
Solenoid solenoid1(13, 70, 70);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Ready");

    solenoid1.Start();
    solenoid1.Update();
    solenoid1.Update();
    solenoid1.Update();
    solenoid1.Update();
    solenoid1.Update();
}
```

I'm just running everything in setup so I can see a few runs.

Can you help me with my clearer stupid mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was erasing my own counter by setting previousMillis = currentMillis. Once I killed that, it started working. I added some other functionality since then, like a delayed start, but this is primarily the same code.

```
void Update() {
//Check to see if it is time to change the state of the solenoid
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

 if((started == true) && (currentMillis - startMillis <= startDelay)) {
  //keep waiting
  Serial.println("Waiting");
 } else if((started == true) && (currentMillis - startMillis < (chargeTime + startDelay) )) {
  //Run
  Serial.print("Run ");
  Serial.println(currentMillis - startMillis);
  digitalWrite(solenoidPin, HIGH);
} else if ((started == true) && (currentMillis - startMillis >= (chargeTime + startDelay) )){
  //Stop
  Serial.print("Stop ");
  Serial.println(currentMillis - startMillis);
  digitalWrite(solenoidPin, LOW);
  started = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the entire setup() void is executing faster than 70ms, meaning you never get to you end position before the 5 calls to solenoid1.Update() complete.

Try this:

```
class Solenoid {
  //Class Variables
  int solenoidPin;
  long chargeTime;
  long ventTime;
  bool started = false;
  unsigned long startMillis;
  unsigned long endMillis;
  unsigned long previousMillis;
  int solenoidState;

  //Constructor
public:
  Solenoid(int pin, long charge, long vent) {
    solenoidPin = pin;
    pinMode(solenoidPin, OUTPUT);
    chargeTime = charge;
    ventTime = vent;
    solenoidState = LOW;
    previousMillis = 0;
}
  void Start() {
    Serial.println("Start called");
    started = true;
  }

  void Update() {
    //Check to see if it is time to change the state of the solenoid
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    Serial.println("Update");
    if((started == true) && (currentMillis-previousMillis <= chargeTime)) {
      //Run
      Serial.print("Run: Charge Time=");
      Serial.print(chargeTime);
      Serial.print("  current-previous=");
      Serial.println(currentMillis-previousMillis);
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
    } else if ((started == true) && (currentMillis-previousMillis >= chargeTime)){
      //Stop
      Serial.println("Stop");
    }
  }
};

//Setup the solenoids
Solenoid solenoid1(13, 70, 70);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Ready");
  solenoid1.Start();
}

void loop(){
  solenoid1.update()
}
```

The rest looks fine to me; if you still have issues try using explicit variable declarations instead of your constructor to troubleshoot if that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering that too. I wound up adding some delay time to the front to compensate and it still happened. Turns out the issue is me setting previousMillis = currentMillis. I'll post my working (and simplified) code.